# How to display multiple values ​of row in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database:

**Persons**

```
user_id | user_name | email |
    1       Jack       ...
    2       Annie      ...
```

**favoriteColors**

```
user_id | color_name |
    1        black
    1        green
    2        blue
```

How can I display all favorite colors by *user_name*? How can I split these multiple values at fetching?

Example for displaying: Jack: black, green | Annie: blue

My sql is like:

```
SELECT user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(color_name SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM Persons
LEFT JOIN favoriteColors ON Persons.user_id = favoriteColors.user_id
GROUP BY Persons.user_id
LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}
```

(`$limit` and `$offset` are sent by ajax)

Comment: You just need to add `WHERE user_name='Jack'` to the query (you could pass the actual username from ajax in the same way as you pass limit and offset values.

Comment: What's the issue here?

Comment: @Nick Thanks! But I would like to display all user_name with their favorite colors.

Comment: Well then what is wrong with your query as it is?

Comment: @Nick The first problem is that, my query displays the user_name 2 times. If I would like to group by user_name (using `group_concat` or object array in php), I won't get the all datas for limit.

Comment: `LIMIT` applies after `GROUP BY`. If you use `LIMIT 10` with `GROUP BY Persons.user_id` you will get data for 10 users. Or do you only want the first 10 favourite colours?

Comment: @Nick Thank you! Could you please show me how can I display it in PHP? If I understand correctly, I have to change my query like `SELECT user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id SEPARATOR ', ') FROM Persons LEFT JOIN favoriteColors ON Persons.user_id = favoriteColors.user_id GROUP BY Persons.user_id LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}`. But I have to split it at fetching, haven't to?

Comment: You want `GROUP_CONCAT(color_name SEPARATOR ', ')` and also `GROUP BY Persons.user_id` but otherwise your query looks fine. You will need to edit your question with more detail about how you want to display the data to get an answer to that part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Aggregate functions for this purpose

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg

```
SELECT p.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.user_name) name, JSON_ARRAYAGG(f.color_name) colors
FROM Persons p
LEFT JOIN favoriteColors f ON p.user_id = f.user_id
WHERE p.user_name = {$username}
GROUP BY p.user_id
LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}
```